# spyOn Jest it is not covering the test even the method it is called

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jestjs

I am having little bit problems to solve the coverage of this Service.

I completed the setup and it says that service is created so i think it is ok, but later when I implement or use the spyOn within jest the method are not getting covered.

Here is some of my code on the service.
Which in his constructor has authService declared.

Auth.service

```
 abstract getUserRoles(roles?: boolean): string[];
   
    hasRole(role: string):boolean {
    const roleLow = role && role.toLowerCase();
    return !!roleLow && this.getUserRoles(true).findIndex(r => roleLow === r.totLowerCase()) > =0;
    }
```

Permissions.service

```
constructor(protected authService: AuthService) {
}

hasPermission(permission: string) {
return this.authService.hasRole(permission);


hasPermissionAdmin() {
return this.hasPermission('App_Admin_permission');
```

And this is how my code for testing looks like.

```
import { TestBed } from "@angular/core/testing"
import { AuthService, PermissionsService } from "services"


describe('Permissions Service', () => {
    let service: PermissionsService;

  const permissionsServiceMock = {
        hasPermission: () => true,
        hasPermissionAdmin: () => true,
      };
  
    beforeEach(() => {
        TestBed.configureTestingModule({
            providers:[
                {provide: PermissionsService, useValue: permissionsServiceMock},
                {provide: AuthService, useValue: MockAuthService},
            ]
        });
        service = TestBed.inject(PermissionsService);
    });
    it('should be created', () => {
        expect(service).toBeTruthy();
      });

      it('should have Admin Permission', () => {
          const spy = jest.spyOn(service, 'hasPermissionAdmin');
          service.hasPermissionAdmin();
          expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
      });
});
```

When I run the coverage with jest it is running/pass but not covering it.
Does anybody has an idea ?

Comment: Why  _would_ you get coverage? You seem to be "testing" a test double of the permissions service against a test double of the authentication service. You're not even exercising the `permissionsServiceMock`, in fact, because you then `spyOn` the methods anyway. All you're testing is that when you call the method you call the method, which is totally pointless - there's no real implementation involved in your tests.

Comment: @jonrsharpe What do you suggest to test there ?

Comment: Test the actual _behaviour_ - how does it interact with the test double of the collaborator, what does it return? `expect(service.hasPermissionAdmin()).toBe(true)`, for example, given appropriate configuration of the authentication service.

Answer (score -1):

Try this :--

```
 it('should have Admin Permission', () => {
          const spy = jest.spyOn(service, 'hasPermission').mockReturnValue(true);
          service.hasPermissionAdmin();
          expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
      });
```

You had mocked the whole function hasPermissionAdmin which you want to invoke, since you mocked it that's why it wont give you coverage instead try to mock its inside logic rather than mocking it entirely.

Comment: Let me know if that works for you

Comment: Nope it is not working it is saying that.
expect(jest.fn()).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(expected)
Expected number of calls : 1
Received number of calls : 0,

Comment: Can you delete this line 
{provide: PermissionsService, useValue: jest.fn()}, from providers since you are expecting to test this service only ?

Comment: But the service needs to be provided right ?
Because I am testing the permissions service

Comment: No it does not need to be in provider section, only dependencies you need to provide in provider section  as you already did in this case AuthService

Comment: The error it is coming, No provider for PermissionsService ?
And as from my knowledge it needs to be declared there

Comment: Can you provide stack error logs there?

Comment: NullInjectorError: R3InjectorError(CompilerModule)[PermissionsService -> PermissionsService]:
      NullInjectorError: No provider for PermissionsService!

Comment: I have chamged the provider for Permissions, see the changes.
I have mocked some functions but still same error.
It expects 1 but it is getting 0.

Comment: can you just simply pass PermissionsService instead of decorating it with usevalue or useclass because it is breaking the purpose of unit testing.

Comment: I have done that but it comes with error.
 Can't resolve all parameters for PermissionsService: (?, ?), then it is saying 
Cannot spyOn on a primitive value; undefined given

Comment: Can you give stackbliz  link where your working code reside let me see and correct it there.

Comment: One more thing please check if authservice has also any dependency then you need to include that also in this service  testbed configuration, that's why I can see it was giving that error

Comment: I found where was the problem, because the permissions service was not added @Injectable, so that caused those errors